Left joining CSV to GeoPackage file and outputting GeoJSON in scalable way with ogr2ogr
I have a large GPKG and a CSV file, and I'd like to (left) join the CSV to the GPKG on one of the columns. A visualisation of what I'm trying to achieve:

Reproducible example
We can create an example GPKG file and an example CSV by using this Python code:
import shapely.geometry
import geopandas as gpd
import pandas as pd

p0 = shapely.geometry.Point([0, 0])

rowCount = 4

gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_dict(
    dict(
        geometry=[p0 for _ in range(rowCount)],
        col0=[f"val{i}" for i in range(rowCount)],
    )
)
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(
    dict(
        col0=[f"val{i}" for i in range(rowCount)],
        col1=[f"some_other_value{i}" for i in range(rowCount)],
    )
).sample(frac=1)

gdf.to_file("base.gpkg",layer="base")
df.to_csv("join.csv")

This code will create a GPKG and a CSV file (for contents, see visualisation above).
We can perform the join using the INDIRECT_SQLITE dialect (why not just stick to simple sqlite? see this thread, or the example under the SELECT statement section of these GDAL docs):
ogr2ogr output.geojson base.gpkg \
   -dialect INDIRECT_SQLITE \
    -sql "SELECT \
            base.geom AS Geometry, \
            base.col0 AS col0, \
            csv.col1 AS col1 \
          FROM \
            base \
          LEFT JOIN \
            'join.csv'.join AS csv \
          ON \
            base.col0 = csv.col0" \
    -nln output

The output is this GeoJSON, as expected:
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"name": "output",
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "col0": "val0", "col1": "some_other_value0" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 0.0, 0.0 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "col0": "val1", "col1": "some_other_value1" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 0.0, 0.0 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "col0": "val2", "col1": "some_other_value2" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 0.0, 0.0 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "col0": "val3", "col1": "some_other_value3" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 0.0, 0.0 ] } }
]
}

Problem
The problem with using INDIRECT_SQLITE the way I do is that runtime seems to scale with the square of the number of rows in the GPKG & CSV files. Runtime visualisation:

I produced the data for this graph in a Jupyter notebook (meaning: lines starting with ! are shell commands rather than Python), this way:
import shapely.geometry
import geopandas as gpd
import pandas as pd
import time

p0 = shapely.geometry.Point([0, 0])
times = {}

for rowCount in [100,400,1000,2000,3000,4000,5000,6000,7000]:

    print(f"rowCount={rowCount}")

    gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_dict(
        dict(
            geometry=[p0 for _ in range(rowCount)],
            col0=[f"val{i}" for i in range(rowCount)],
        )
    )
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(
        dict(
            col0=[f"val{i}" for i in range(rowCount)],
            col1=[f"some_other_value{i}" for i in range(rowCount)],
        )
    ).sample(frac=1)

    !rm -f base.gpkg
    !rm -f join.csv
    !rm -f output.geojson
    
    gdf.to_file("base.gpkg",layer="base")
    df.to_csv("join.csv")

    t0 = time.time()

    !\
    ogr2ogr output.geojson base.gpkg \
    -dialect INDIRECT_SQLITE \
        -sql "SELECT \
                base.geom AS Geometry, \
                base.col0 AS col0, \
                csv.col1 AS col1 \
            FROM \
                base \
            LEFT JOIN \
                'join.csv'.join AS csv \
            ON \
                base.col0 = csv.col0" \
        -nln output

    times[rowCount]=time.time()-t0

Code for the plot itself:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot(times.keys(),times.values(),c="blue")
plt.scatter(times.keys(),times.values(),c="red")
plt.xlabel("rowCount")
plt.ylabel("Runtime (sec)")

Question
How can I use ogr2ogr to left join a CSV to a GPKG file and produce a GeoJSON output in a scalable way?
By "scalable" I mean: the expected runtime for a large number of lines to join grows linearly.

One possible solution is to load the CSV file to the GPKG file as a new layer. Once it's in the GPKG, there is no need for INDIRECT_SQLITE! So:
ogr2ogr -update base.gpkg join.csv -nln csv

ogr2ogr base.geojson base.gpkg \
    -sql "SELECT \
           base.geom AS Geometry, \
           base.col0 AS col0, \
           csv.col1 AS col1 \
         FROM base \
         LEFT JOIN csv \
         ON base.col0 = csv.col0" \
    -nln output

Scaling (includes both the CSV -> GPKG & GPKG -> GeoJSON steps):


We can also create an index on base.col0 and csv.col0 (source) before the JOIN operation:
ogr2ogr -update base.gpkg join.csv -nln csv

ogrinfo -sql "CREATE INDEX base_col0_idx ON base (col0)" base.gpkg
ogrinfo -sql "CREATE INDEX csv_col0_idx ON csv (col0)" base.gpkg

ogr2ogr base.geojson base.gpkg \
     -sql "SELECT \
            base.geom AS Geometry, \
            base.col0 AS col0, \
            csv.col1 AS col1 \
        FROM base \
        LEFT JOIN csv \
        ON base.col0 = csv.col0" \
     -nln output

Indexing seems to help a bit when the number of geometries becomes large:

and more when the number of geometries is even larger:


Create indexes on base.col0 and csv.col0 and make new tests. I would also try if csv could be imported into another SQLite database and then attached into the main database for running the query. It could make it easier for you to manage the data.
